# InputField : only integer or list of integers in a specific range

Tags: dynamic, conditional, inputfield

I'm making a dynamic structure which reads some output from a FEM program (node results).

I'd like an inputfield in which I specify the number(s) of the nodes I am interested in. The value of the InputField can only be an Integer or a list of integers in a specific range.

Let's say we have only 10 nodes, then the only values the InputField can take are :

{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

I want to be sure that the user will not be able to put values like {0,11,Pi,...} and if he does, the InputField returns 1.

It may be something like :

(Which sure not working.)

```
TotalnumberOfnode = 10;
InputField[Dynamic[nodeNumber, {Integer,Element@Range[TotalnumberOfnode]}]]
```

(Working one but not for lists)

```
 TotalnumberOfnode = 10;
 InputField[
  Dynamic[nodeNumber, 
   Function[If[And[TotalnumberOfnode >= # >= 1, IntegerQ[#]], 
    nodeNumber = #]]] 
 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Let me have second look. The parsing is not restting nodenumber since it is dynamic., It is only doing the parsing now. Will delete my answer for now.

Comment: try `Function[If[And[TotalnumberOfnode >= # >= 1, IntegerQ[#]] || 
   And[ListQ[#], TotalnumberOfnode >= Max@# >= 1], nodeNumber = #]]` in the second argument of `Dynamic`?

Comment: @kglr Nice, I modified a bit your solution to avoid the user to be able to insert 0 in a list. However, it is still possible to insert non-integers in a list. `InputField[
 Dynamic[nodeNumber, 
  Function[If[
    And[TotalnumberOfnode >= # >= 1, IntegerQ[#]] || 
     And[ListQ[#], TotalnumberOfnode >= Max@#, Min@# >= 1], 
    nodeNumber = #]]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option. Might want to improve it to handle Null better.

```
InputField[
  Dynamic[
    num, 
    (num = First[Nearest[Range[TotalnumberOfnode], #, 1]]) &], 
  Number, 
  ContinuousAction -> True]
```

Comment: Work great for single number but not for lists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant way but it does the job :

```
InputField[
Dynamic[nodeNumber, 
  Function[
   If[
    Or[
    And[TotalnumberOfnode >= # >= 1, IntegerQ[#]], 
    And[TotalnumberOfnode >= Max@#, Min@# >= 1,ListQ[#],VectorQ[#, IntegerQ]
  ]
 ]
```